# Installing on encrypted HDDs

Tags: linux-mint, kali-linux, encryption, tpm

I am trying to install kali linux on one SSD and linux mint on the other SSD.

Both instalations are encrypted using LVM encryption. Linux mint works great and also kali linux boots up the first time after instalation.

After I take out SSD with kali linux and insert SSD with linux mint everything works and linux mint boots up with no problems. However when I take out linux mint and insert kali linux SSD it wont boot up and my BIOS states that there is no bootable media.

I have heard that there could be a problem with TPM so I disabled it in BIOS (without clearing cache to ensure that mint would boot up) and then I have installed kali with TPM disabled but it still isn't working.

I do care about linux mint instalation because there are a lot of data but I can do whatever I want with kali because it is fresh install. Any ideas how to acomplish this?

Comment: what do you mean by removing ssd's ??? 
1. both are connected and removing 1st and then trying.. or both are connected removing 2nd and then trying...
2. BOTH are NOT connected just trying by using only one ssd at a time???

Comment: last option is correct. I always have only ONE ssd connected. I am using a HDD bay for this so when I want to work on mint I insert ssd with mint (kali ssd is out at that time) and when I want to switch I turn off pc and insert other ssd (with kali installed)

Comment: so you must have been choosing your OS from the boot menu of the bios...while booting your pc.. whenever you change your ssd

Comment: when I switch back to kali as I mentioned and chose it as bootable media it says that no bootable media was found so it looks like that after reinserting kali boot sector just breaks. However this does not happen with mint

Comment: yes offcourse it is yeilding the correct message because it is unable to find the any active bootable disk... and to help you with that i will suggest to remove your important partitions and also take backup of any important data... and do let me know when you finish all that stuff.  and leave a message here.. using your smartphone or another pc.. and you will have to perform some steps.. and also have to tell me the immediate output.. and after some steps... you will be ready to boot into your OS.. in the way you want..

Comment: Will this require me to reinstall Mint?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you installed something to the Kali SSD while the Linux Mint SSD was still in the machine. As a result, Kali installed its boot blocks to the first SSD in the machine (i.e., the Linux Mint one) rather than the SSD on which it was installed.

If you're never going to boot Kali when both SSDs are in the machine, the easiest way forward is to remove the Linux Mint SSD from your machine, boot from the Kali installation media, and choose a "rescue mode" option. Then, have it make the system bootable again.

Alternatively, you can also reinstall Kali if it doesn't have any data that you need anymore, and you don't find the rescue mode or it doesn't have the "make system bootable again" option. Just make sure the Linux Mint SSD is not in the system when you do.

Comment: I had only one SSD in notebook at the time so it means that when I was installing kali there was only empty SSD in machine and I installed kali to it. Mint SSD was not inserted at that time